# Customization of related list

Tags: visualforce

I want to customize the related list notes & attachment. I need to put both notes and attachment in separate sections in Lead. I have tried using VisualForce but with no success. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Can you provide a bit more information as to what it is your trying to achieve so that we can provide a better answer to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't customize the Notes & Attachments related list yet - there is a Salesforce Idea article you can vote on - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000k6xGAAQ